# Where can I find Ubuntu's kernel source code?

Tags: kernel, documentation, source-code

I heard that Ubuntu is open source and that all its source code is available, but I have never seen its code. I want to start learning about Ubuntu's kernel and its complete working.Please suggest me some reading from where I can start.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the source code of ubuntu kernel, using

`sudo apt-get install linux-source`

A bzip file will be downloaded at `/usr/src/` containing the source code.

However, ubuntu codes are taken from the orginal linux kernel which is available for download at http://www.kernel.org/.

To understand the kernel, you must start with basics of operating system.How kernel works, a general idea about subsystem/modules/drivers. Also needed very good knowledge C (specially pointers). Otherwise jumping into code of linux kernel won't help at all.